# Python-pandas "read_csv" is not reading the whole .TXT file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, bigdata

First of all, I have found several questions with the same title/topic here and I have tried the solutions that have been suggested, but none has worked for me

Here is the **issue**:
I want to extract a sample of workers from a huge .txt file (> 50 GB)
I am using HPC cluster for this purpose.

Every row in the data represents a worker which has many info (column variables). The idea is to a extract subsample of workers based on the first two letters in the ID variable:

```
df = pd.read_csv('path-to-my-txt-file', encoding= 'ISO-8859-1', sep = '\t', low_memory=False, error_bad_lines=False, dtype=str)
df = df.rename(columns = {'Worker ID' : 'worker_id'})

# extract subsample based on first 2 lettter in worker id
new_df = df[df.worker_id.str.startswith('DK', na=False)]
new_df.to_csv('DK_worker.csv', index = False)
```

The **problem** is that the resulting .CSV file has only 10-15 % of the number of rows that should be there (I have another source of information on the approximate number of rows that I should expect).

I think the data has some encoding issues. I have tried something like 'utf-8', 'latin_1' .. nothing has changed.

Do you see anything wrong in this code that may cause this problem? have I missed some argument?

*I am not a Python exper*t :)

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can't load a 50GB file into your computers RAM, it would not be possible to store that much data. And I doubt the csv module can handle files of that size. What you need to do is open the file in small pieces, then process each piece.

```
def process_data(piece):
    # process the chunk ...

def read_in_chunks(file_object, chunk_size=1024):
    while True:
        data = file_object.read(chunk_size)
        if not data:
            break
        yield data


with open('path-to-my-txt-file.csv') as f:
    for piece in read_in_chunks(f):
        process_data(piece)
```

Comment: Dear Jared, thanks for your response. You are totally right, but you missed one of my sentences up there, I am using HPC or High-Performance Cluster of computers (256 GB RAM + 28 Core-CPUS), Sorry, I had to be clear about this. 
I will try to read the file in chunks as you suggested.